# Reference javascript in Blazor only for pages that use a specific layout

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a main layout, and an additional layout for a sub section of my appliction.  That sub section needs additional javascript but the entire application does not.

My problem is that if I try to add script elements to my nested layout I get a compile error

> Error (active)    RZ9992  Script tags should not be placed inside
> components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this,
> move the script tag to the 'index.html' file or another static
> location. For more information, see https://aka.ms/AAe3qu3

This is because Blazor doesn't want me adding script references inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically.  I don't quite follow what is meant by that, but what is the workaround for this?

My app is set up with a default app.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And a default _host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@namespace Blazor_Server_App.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

My _Layout.cshtml is pretty much standard template stuff:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace Blazor_Server_App.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="fullheight fixed-footer">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="Blazor Server App.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src='lib/jquery/jquery.js' ype="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js' ype="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have my MainLayout.razor page:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<HeadContent>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site/Site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="icons/mainmenu/style.css" />
</HeadContent>
...
@code {}
```

Now I have my nested layout page that I use for some of my pages. All pages using this nested layout need additional javascript and css that other pages don't need.  This is where I get the compile error

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@layout MainLayoutTopNav

<HeadContent>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css" />
</HeadContent>

<PageTitle>Samples</PageTitle>

@Body

@*Compile error here...*@
<script src="Sample.js"></script>
```

And here is a page that uses my nested layout.

```
@page "/Samples"
@layout SampleLayout
...

@code {

}
```

Comment: Script loader in JSInterop should help you, but keep in mind the rendering process. If your Javascript does some initialization/event binding on some HTML elements, it will be cancelled when/if those elements are rerendered.

Comment: see this info -https://shauncurtis.github.io/posts/DynamicCss.html

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can load js in OnAfterRender with special js loader.

Create Special JS file with this script and save to file with scriptloader.js name on your wwwroot/js/ on client project.

```
    // store list of what scripts we've loaded
loaded = [];

// loadScript: returns a promise that completes when the script loads
window.loadScript = function (scriptPath, isasync, isdefer) {
    // check list - if already loaded we can ignore
    if (loaded[scriptPath]) {
        return new this.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve();
        });
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // create JS library script element
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = scriptPath;
        script.async = isasync;
        script.defer = isdefer;

        script.type = "text/javascript";

        // flag as loading/loaded
        loaded[scriptPath] = true;

        // if the script returns okay, return resolve
        script.onload = function () {
            resolve(scriptPath);
        };

        // if it fails, return reject
        script.onerror = function () {
            reject(scriptPath);
        }

        // scripts will load at end of body
        document["body"].appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

add scriptloader.js on index.html

```
<script src="/js/scriptloader.min.js"></script>
```

add OnAfterRender code to load any special js file:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("loadScript", "JSFILENAME.js");
}
```

you can use this scriptloader.js to load any js file for layout or pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it can also be done this way. Using `SectionOutlet` and `SectionContent`.
The reference article is here: [ASP.NET Core Blazor sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0).